# Bash's read builtin with multiline

Tags: bash, read

Each time the read builtin is executed it parses the next line of the input, but where in the man page is this mentioned? How would I know this beforehand?

EDIT
I guess @dirkt answered this.

Answer (score 3):

From `man bash`:

> read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
>
> **One line** is read from the standard input, [...]

It's in the section labeled SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but does "read from stdin" mean that you are modifying stdin?

Comment: @zagortenay333 `stdin` by default refers to input from keyboard, so if you're reading from `stdin` it just means reading what you type in. Modifying `stdin` would mean reading from file or from pipe, so whatever text comes in from file or from pipe will be treated as input. See this for example: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23595339/  The command is `cat | while read line ; do echo "You said" "$line" ; done` . I am typing in something to cat, and cat forwards it via pipe to read. By the way, `while read line; do . . . done` is very common way for reading multiline input

Comment: I know that.. What I don't understand is how the phrase "read one line from stdin" means that the next time I read it it will be the next line of the input.

Comment: The input here has multiple lines.

Comment: Reading is usually sequentially, and "consumes" what you've read from the source (or advances the file position, etc.)

Comment: @zagortenay333 no, it means `read` will take in all characters *until* it sees newline character, and will stop. Next line you put in won't be read. That's why you need `while read VAR; do . . done` if you want to read more than one line.

Comment: @dirkt Oh. Well thx then :).

Comment: @zagortenay333 see this maybe this can help: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23595386/

Comment: @Serg You didn't understand what I'm asking. I know why I need a while loop.

Comment: @zagortenay333  ok. So what exactly you're asking then ? Can you clarify or at least provide example of what confuses you ?

Comment: I didn't understand that each time it reads the input the file position advances. I thought each time it reads that it would start all over again.. XD

Comment: @zagortenay333 Well, technically speaking it does start over each time. It reads only until it sees newline character and goes "OK, my job is done here, I'll save stuff into variable".  If you're reading something from file, it won't advance by itself, because it's not `read`'s job. It just waits for input. That's why `cat` or `<` is used to give text to `read`

Comment: Another builtin `mapfile` (alias `readarray`) allows reading multiple lines.